# mootools | how to load and execute JSON string

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm using a mootools javascript library and would like to load JSON string with script.
After loading I would like to execute this script. Is it possible using great mootools framework?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which Mootools version you are using? are you using `request()`(ajax)?, what script do you want to run (I supose on the ajax success callback) ?

Comment: You want to check Request.JSONP from mootools-more. although if you load a script you load a script, it's not JSON.

Answer (score 2):

```
new Element('script',{'type': 'text/javascript', 'html': json.response}).inject(document.body, 'bottom');
```